# How to make content stay inside div

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to achive the following using CSS:

[image]

But the written content won't stay inside de wrapper div, like this:

[image]

I tried using material-ui Grid but it doesn't work as well.. Thanks for the help!

Sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/produto2-98yl7?file=/src/Produto2.js

Comment: if you want to use styles.css, do not forget to import it https://codesandbox.io/s/produto2-forked-o08tp?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Semantic UI's Floated Line](https://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html) for this.

Its at the very bottom of the page.